# Integrating IC transceivers on a pcb

Tags: integrated-circuit, transceiver, nrf24l01

I have a question about the difference between transceiver modules and transceiver ICs.

I want to integrate a 2.4GHz transceiver IC - nRF24L01+ onto a PCB instead of using the NRF 24l01+ module.

What are the steps I have to take or components I have to add to get it to work?

Do I have to add an antenna like the module version has to the PCB?

Comment: You should explain **why** you want to use the IC instead of the module. To make the IC work you *basically* need the same components as are present on the module. As you're asking this, my guess is that you do not have much experience with doing this and that is exactly why modules exist: to make **your** life easy and give **you** more chance of success. I am sure that you **will** have issues using the IC on its own unless you **exactly** duplicate the module. Then why not just get the module instead?

Comment: *do i have to add an antenna like the module version has to the PCB* If you want working transceiver then an Antenna is needed, the antenna is an essential part of wireless communication devices. Why do you think you would not need an antenna?

Comment: No, I don't have a lot of experience with this, that's why I was wondering what the exact differences are between the module and the IC, I thought there was already an antenna imbedded in the chip. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 4):

You start by looking up the [datasheet for the nRF24L01.](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/nRF24L01_prelim_prod_spec_1_2.pdf)

In it, you will find all the information about what it takes to use that chip.

You will also find this circuit diagram:

[image]

Right under the schematic is a parts list:

[image]

That should answer your question about what you need.

And, yes, you **must** include an antenna.

---

Virtually every project that involves an IC starts with reading the datasheet.

You look it up, see what it says about requirements and operating conditions (powersupply voltage and temperature range and **all** kinds of other stuff.)  Maybe you can't use it because it is only rated down to 0 degrees celsius and you need to use it in an unheated cabin in Antarctica.

You see how you can connect it to the rest of your circuit. (Oh, it uses SPI.  My microprocessor doesn't have a SPI port.  Can I do SPI via bitbanging?)

And, you see what connections it needs to the outside world. ( Oh.  It needs an antenna and a matching network.  Can I integrate a ready made antenna?  What effect will the circuit board material have on the matching network?)

Finally, you have the certification problem that Damien mentioned:  Can you handle all the details well enough that your finished product will make it through the  certification process?

---

Given the level of your questions ("Do I need an antenna?")  I would doubt your ability to do it well enough to get it certified - that's a tough job, and I know that I (as a hobbyist) couldn't do it.

If this is for a hobby project - go for it.  You might manage something that works.

If this is a commercial project:  stick to the module, or get assistance from a more experienced engineer to design your own.

Comment: Alright I think that answers all my questions, sorry if it was a simple one but I couldn't find any steps or info on how to integrate an IC or how a module is made

Answer (score 2):

One of the big difference is that most modules are certified for RF.

If you need to make a product that you want to sell, and design the RF part (even just copy a design) you will have to go through the expensive and lengthy certification process for the different countries.

Besides that, you will also need to do some antenna tuning, requiring some expensive hardware.

If you want to go ahead, the simplest method is to get a transceiver chip in which the datasheet will provide you a reference design that you can copy on your design including components and antenna layout.

Comment: Alright thanks for the answer, I wanted to use the standalone chip because it's cheaper but I guess if I have to add the antenna and components it would be cheaper to just use the module version

Comment: By experience, it's cheaper to use the standalone chip. Usually modules are quite expensive and one of the reason it's because they are certified.

Comment: @Damien not fully my experience – RF circuitry often benefits from 4 layers instead of 2 – but a large 4 layer board is expensive! So, only putting the RF circuitry on a small 4 layer board that has been produced in the thousands makes the overall product cheaper – not even including things like the inevitable testing and revisions.

Comment: NRF24L01 cost 12$, the chip cost 1.2$. Even you factor the rest of the BOM you will end up around 2$. 4 layers board are cheap to make nowaday and assembly has to be done anyway. As I said, testing / certification is where you will have the cost difference.